# Spikes in response time for S#arpArchitecture site deployed on AppHarbor

Tags: s#arp-architecture, appharbor

The response times reported by Pingdom for my site deployed on AppHarbor are generally around half that for when it was deployed on Discount.ASP, however there are some spikes where the response time jumps to around 26 seconds, what is causing these spikes? My guess is that this is due to app pool recycling, what is the best way to reduce or eliminate these spikes?

The site is using ASP.Net MVC and S#arpArchitecture.

[image: Response times from Pingdom]

Comment: Is there a pattern to the spikes? Does it happen every 20 minutes or whatever the default is for the app pool? If so, then it must be the app pool recycling, and they way I have dealt with this in the past, is either by having a script running on an interval so the site would stay warm (was ok for my usages for low traffic site), or if it is a high traffic site then we dealt with it at the load balancer level (if responce takes > 1 sec take the server out of load balancer) and requests would be served from other servers that are not recycling.

Comment: Pingdom is pinging the site every 5 minutes, so it should be warm. Also, the table above shows all response times over 5 seconds since deploying on 12/04/2012, I can't see any pattern. This is on the free plan at AppHarbor, so I guess they could be moving it from one server to another. The other possibility is that Pingdom is not reporting the response times correctly.

Comment: Are these related to first page-load after a deploy? The ASP.NET engine has to compile views, etc. before serving the first request after a new version is deployed. We're working on ways to reduce this.

Comment: No, the site was deployed on 12/04/2012 at 12:40pm. The Pingdom check hits the home page (http://flagbinlive.apphb.com), which is a plain MVC view i.e. no database access.

Comment: Have you tried [installing New Relic](https://appharbor.com/addons/newrelic) to see where the long-running requests hang?

Comment: Just installed New Relic, not used it before but boy is it good!, will give it sometime to collect the relevant data.

Comment: A spike has occurred again around 10:05am today (20/04/2012). New Relic shows a response time of 15.5s and Pingdom gives a response time of 27.9s, not sure why the big difference, but I'm inclined to trust New Relic more than Pingdom. New Relic shows that the Application_BeginRequest is being called when these spikes occur. The app is a multi-tenant app and intialises a number of NHibernate session factories, I need to look at how best to use the configuration cache to speed this up (most likely store it in Amazons S3).

Comment: Whilst I was expecting the app pool to be recycled or the app to move between servers, I wasn't expecting it to happen quite so often, and in fact it rarely happened when hosted on DiscountASP.Net, why does it happen so often on AppHarbor?

Comment: The application pool is recycled after 20min of inactivity by IIS, but that's not likely to happen if Pingdom hits your site more frequently.

Comment: OK, now that New Relic has got a bit more data I can see that the spikes occur every 29 hours, so I guess that the AppHarbor IIS servers are using the default setting for app pool recylcing every 1740 minutes. Is it possible to change this setting so that the app pool is never recycled?

Comment: No, it's not something we're planning on changing. It's also a good way to ensure that any slow memory-leaks in your app don't get out of control. You should look into reducing app startup time by reducing initialization logic and using view precompilation.

Comment: Will this be an issue if I have multiple web workers? Are the recycling times staggered?